# Zend Framework command to remove an action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework, and i am attempting to remove an action using ZF command line tools.  However, i am not able to do so.  Basically, there's a function to an action in my controller that i wish to remove.  I created the action using the following command:

```
Action
    zf create action name controller-name[=Index] view-included[=1] module
```

Is there a command to remove it?

Comment: AFAIK  there is no command like this one

Comment: so, i suppose we have to manually remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no command in Zend_Tool for that. You need to do that manually, by removing the action method in the controller and deleting the view script. You have also to edit the .zfproject.xml in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove any controller or action manually, you have to also edit .zfproject.xml file on the root of your project, otherwise it will not allow you to create that controller or action in future again with zend tool.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your application root and edit .zfproject.xml file. This is the file, where zf command will create each controller and action log. remove those actions from there and from controller files and also the views.